# How to display a web page in navigation-bar app?

Tags: android, navigationbar

I am currently creating an android application in which I use the location and 2 symbol Id's of the user to create an aprs comressed packet, and I need in one screen to ask the user for input and show him the content of the packet.

But I also need to display a web page, therefore I need to know if it is possible to use web interface to display a web page in a navigation bar application ? (the type of the app was decided since I need one screen for input and output and one screen for the web page).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but have you tried using Webview?

Comment: is web view a way to display on screen a web page and use the functions it offers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Chrome Custom Tabs
[link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could understand you should use 'WebView' to show webpage, further you can use interfaces to communicate between web page JavaScript code and android code.
Please refer following links :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html